# Undefined reference to static constexpr templated member

Tags: c++, templates, static, constexpr

I have a template class for compile-time generation of a CRC table.

```
// crcTable.h
template <typename T, T polynomial, bool reversed>
struct CrcTable
{
    //...
}
```

I want an instance of this class as static constexpr member of my CRC16 class

```
// crc16.h
template<uint16_t polynomial = 0x1021, uint16_t initialValue = 0xFFFF>
class Crc16
{
public:
    //...
private:
    static constexpr CrcTable<uint16_t, polynomial, false> crcTable = CrcTable<uint16_t, polynomial, false>{};
}
```

As this is a static member I need to define it in a source file

```
// crc16.cpp
template <uint16_t polynomial, uint16_t initialValue>
constexpr CrcTable<uint16_t, polynomial, false> Crc16<polynomial, initialValue>::crcTable;
```

Compiling this gives me the following error:

> undefined reference to `Crc16<(unsigned short)4129, (unsigned
> short)65535>::crcTable' clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Hint:** if I define with `inline` in the header file it compiles and links successfully.

```
// crc16.h
template <uint16_t polynomial, uint16_t initialValue>
inline constexpr CrcTable<uint16_t, polynomial, false> Crc16<polynomial, initialValue>::crcTable;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible with templates what I am trying to do?